# Assign collection to query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a module which returns timesheet records. When there is a scope parameter provided the items method scopes the timesheets so it only returns certain timesheets. How can I use the result of that query in another query? It is about using `team_users` in the `super.where(user_id: team_users)` query.

```
module Collections
  class TimesheetCollection < Collection

    module TeamScope
      def items
        if params[:scope].present?
          team_users = User.from_team(@manager)
          super.where(user_id: team_users)
        else
          super
        end
      end
    end

    attr_reader :ability, :params

    def initialize(ability, params, manager)
      @ability = ability
      @params  = params
      @manager = manager
      extend TeamScope
    end

    def items
      Timesheet.unscoped
    end

    def paginated
      extend Pagination
      self
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for active record you can pass in an [array of ids/values](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects). For your query you could try to do something like this:

```
team_users = User.from_team(@manager)
super.where(user_id: team_users.collect{|u| u.id})
```